# Isomorphism between quotient groups with normal subgroups

Tags: quotient-spaces, abstract-algebra

I'm looking at a problem in my textbook and it says:

Let $ψ : G_1 → G_2$ be a surjective group homomorphism. Let $H_1$ be a normal subgroup of $G_1$ and suppose that $ψ(H_1) = H_2$. Prove or disprove that $G_1/H_1$ is isomorphic $G_2/H_2$.

So far, I know that since $H_1$ is normal in $G_1$, $H_2$ is also normal in $G_2$. I'm unsure how to proceed from here though, can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is wrong. Just take $G_1=\mathbb{Z}_2$, $H_1=\{0\}$, $G_2=\{0\}$. Then $H_2=\{0\}$ and $G_1/H_1=\mathbb{Z}_2$ is not isomorphic to $G_2/H_2=\{0\}$.

Comment: If G1 was isomorphic to G2, this would be true right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider the mapping $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}^\infty\to\mathbb{Z}^\infty$ sending $(z_1,z_2,\ldots)$ to $(z_2,z_3,\ldots)$, and assume $H_1$ generated by $(2,0,0,\ldots)$. Then, $\varphi(H_1)=\{0\}$, and $\mathbb{Z}^\infty/H_1$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^\infty$ because the former contains a finite order element.

Answer (score 1):

This only holds if $ψ^{-1}(H_2)=H_1$, then use the isomorphism theorem:

$G_1 \to G_2 \to G_2/H_2$ is surjective. The kernel of the composition is then $H_1$. Now apply the isomorphism theorem and you're done.

Otherwise you could take for example $Z\times Z \to Z$ by $(1,1)\mapsto 1$ then the kernel is generated by $(1,-1)$ and you could take $H_1 = 0 \times Z$, but $Z \neq 0$.

Comment: Why is the kernel of the composition $H_1$?

Comment: Are you aware, that every element in $H_1$ goes to the trivial element?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of what a kernel is, but I'm wondering why the kernel of this composition is $H_1$?

Comment: Hmm, is it because $H_2$ is the kernel of $G_2 -> G_2/H_2$, and $H_1$ is mapped to $H_2$?

Comment: In other words, if we call the composition $\pi\Psi$ then $ker\pi\Psi = (\pi\Psi)^{-1}(e) = \Psi^{-1}(\pi{-1}(e))= \Psi^{-1}(ker \pi)= \Psi^{-1}(H_2) = H_1$.